# How to get record and display it?

Tags: odoo-11

I'm writing a function that for searching record.

while I change the text of name fields I hope odoo will give back the record and post it.

I have refered to odoo origin code, but it did not work.

```py
@api.multi
    @api.onchange('name')
    def _search_name(self):
        if self._context.get('params')['action'] == 111:
            return {
                'res_id': self.env['yc.purchase'].search([('name', '=', self.name)]).id,
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_model': 'yc.purchase',
                'view_id': False,
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            }
```

I hope the url will from

[image]

Comment: You cannot open a new form inside a method with an `onchange` decorator. At least not without modifying the core of Odoo.

Comment: But while I filling in another text in field of name, I can get the record that I want from module"yc.purchase" in debug mode. Is it impossible to link to another record without modiflying Odoo core?

Comment: So if the user is typing a name and the typed text matches a record name of `yp.purchase` model in the database, this one must be suddenly opened in a form view and avoid user to keep writing? In this case I guess you would have to create your own widget with JavaScript and add it to the field `name` in the XML view.

Comment: In other word, I want to search a name and checkout his profile. So I type his name down. After finish this the function will bring out the data of that name and display it on screen.All this data store at same module. The method you described seems hard for me. I don't have any experience in writing Js code on Odoo. But I will find out. If you have any demonstration code that will be a great help. all in all thanks.

Comment: The easiest solution (no JavaScript) would be to put a button next to the search field, and once you have typed down the string to search, click on this button to show the results. Is this solution OK for you or you need to show the result as soon as the typed string matches any record in the database?

Comment: No, I have tried that before,Odoo will return error. Because odoo will add new record of the search name to db immediately. So that there are two record have same "name" in db. It will raise error.

Comment: I understand. And if you create a new form for searching, this form would show the data of a Transient Model. This would have two fields, a `Char` (to type the searched string) and a `One2many` (to show the found results). In that case you could show the list of the results as soon as your typed text matches a record (no button, you could do it in the `onchange` of the `Char` field). Then you could open any of the results by clicking on them (opening its form view in pop-up) or by clicking on a button placed in each line (to open its form view using the whole screen).

Comment: okay, but is this way can save data?  Requirements cloud include searching follow by editing and storing.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the model in onchange method for that either click on a button or perform action. You can return warning in onchange.

Comment: return {'warning': {
            'title': _('Record'),
            'message': _('Your data.')
        }

Comment: Do you mean I change module "yc.purchase" to another module?the code is in the same module "yc.purchase".

Comment: no you cant change the model you can only show data in warning for changing model you have to click on a button or perform any action.

Comment: oh, sorry, my expression have some problems. what I mean is I don't want to change module, I'd like to get another record in the same module "yc.purchase" and display it. Is it possible?

Comment: You can add a field and put data in that field on onchnage

Comment: the data have been brought out which will be edit and save. so I'd like to get whole record in order to modify.

Comment: Then you cant get that on onchange direct with odoo.

Answer (score 0):

I use a stupid and dangerous way to reach the idea.

The process is type down the name which you wanna to search.
While clicking button, db immediately create a new record contain nothing except name field.
And after entering function, I delete it.
So that it would not raise error.

**my view.xml**

```xml
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="process_data_entry_form">
            <field name="name">pde.form</field>
            <field name="model">yc.purchase</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="ProcessDataEntry form">
                    <sheet>
                        <group col="8">
                        </group>
                        <div>
                            <button string="search name" type="object" name="yc_purchase_search_name"/>
                        </div>
```

**my mudule.py**

```py
@api.multi
    # @api.onchange("name")
    def yc_purchase_search_name(self,):
        # if url action = 111 execute function
        if self._context.get('params')['action'] == 111:
            # delete the empty record just create by odoo
            to_delete_id = self.env["yc.purchase"].search([('name', '=', self.name)],order='id desc',limit=1).id
            sql = "delete from yc_purchase where id=%d" % to_delete_id
            self._cr.execute(sql)
            id = self.env['yc.purchase'].search([('name', '=', self.name)]).id
            return {
                'res_model': 'yc.purchase',
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_id': id,
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'view_id': self.env.ref('yc_root.process_data_entry_form').id,
                'target': 'inline',
            }
```

the result as down below.
[image]

I think this method is really dangerus.

any greater idea?